# IIS Restrict anonymous ftp users to a particular directory

Tags: iis-7, ftp, anonymous

I have ftp configured on IIS7.

I would like to restrict ftp access by anonymous users to a particular downloads folder only.

Where do I specify which directory anonymous users should be restricted to?

Comment: Already tried searching on google. There are a lot of solutions for isolating users after they log in. But where do you send anonymous users?

Comment: Into FTP Service Root Folder, like in advanced settings of the ftp service.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have the anonymous users start out in whatever directory you want to restrict them to, and then set permissions so they only have access to that directory?

Comment: Consider me a total IIS noob. That is exactly what I wanted to do, send them(anonymous users) to a particular dir and not give access to anything else. Couldn't figure out how.

Comment: You did figure this out, yes?  If not, let me know and I'll post instructions.

Comment: No, I couldn't figure out the solution. But I installed FileZilla server and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to disable anonymous authentication on FTP root folder, in FTP authentication settings, and add allow rule for anonymous access in FTP authorization rules only for specific directories.

That should work.